# clap.rs not printing colors during `--help`

Tags: rust, clap

So I migrated from clap v3.x to v4.x.
I am not getting the color during the help output as I got it in v3.x. Everything was completely white. I used the basic code from the example (https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/blob/master/examples/git.rs).
Below are two images showing the output of v3 (the first one) and the production from v4 (the second one).

My question is, how to add the colors?
[image: v3]

[image: v4]

I tried setting the color to Always but no help

Comment: This is documented as part of [polishing `--help` output](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/issues/4132) and [PR4117](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/pull/4117)

Comment: So we don't have any option to rollback to the original one till now in v4.x, right?

Comment: I have the same problem and tried lots of tutorials, however I do not get the colors. The help page does not look modern at all.

Comment: I had the same problem and still haven't found a solution

Comment: One trap I hit: if you use `try_parse` and handle failures yourself, it's easy to print the error in a way that loses the styling. Make sure to use `Error::print`. https://github.com/sourcefrog/clap-colors-example has a full example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create the styles yourself

```rust
pub fn get_styles() -> clap::builder::Styles {
    clap::builder::Styles::styled()
        .usage(
            anstyle::Style::new()
                .bold()
                .underline()
                .fg_color(Some(anstyle::Color::Ansi(anstyle::AnsiColor::Yellow))),
        )
        .header(
            anstyle::Style::new()
                .bold()
                .underline()
                .fg_color(Some(anstyle::Color::Ansi(anstyle::AnsiColor::Yellow))),
        )
        .literal(
            anstyle::Style::new().fg_color(Some(anstyle::Color::Ansi(anstyle::AnsiColor::Green))),
        )
        .invalid(
            anstyle::Style::new()
                .bold()
                .fg_color(Some(anstyle::Color::Ansi(anstyle::AnsiColor::Red))),
        )
        .error(
            anstyle::Style::new()
                .bold()
                .fg_color(Some(anstyle::Color::Ansi(anstyle::AnsiColor::Red))),
        )
        .valid(
            anstyle::Style::new()
                .bold()
                .underline()
                .fg_color(Some(anstyle::Color::Ansi(anstyle::AnsiColor::Green))),
        )
        .placeholder(
            anstyle::Style::new().fg_color(Some(anstyle::Color::Ansi(anstyle::AnsiColor::White))),
        )
}
```

And then call it with styles

```rust
#[command(styles=get_styles())]
pub struct CliArgs {
...
}
```

Comment: This should definitively be *the* answer to the question, not the other one that suggests using Python...

Comment: Great answer.  If you just want the default styling (no color but with bold highlighting) use `#[command(styles=styles=clap::builder::Styles::styled())]`

Comment: FYI, it appears that styles are now considered stable and the `unstable_styles` feature has been removed: https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/pull/5094

Comment: FYI, per the docs, here is how to get v3-like styling: https://docs.rs/clap_builder/4.4.12/clap_builder/builder/styling/struct.Styles.html

`# use clap_builder as clap;
# use clap::builder::styling::*;
let styles = Styles::styled()
    .header(AnsiColor::Yellow.on_default())
    .usage(AnsiColor::Green.on_default())
    .literal(AnsiColor::Green.on_default())     
    .placeholder(AnsiColor::Green.on_default());`

Answer (score 7):

Color defaults were (very sadly) removed in v4 of clap.
I agree that this is huge regression -- as it makes scanning by users much more difficult and usage less pleasant for most people.

The main author's reason comes down to wanting to support everything and color not being on everything.

They are working on optional colors.  So ... someday, maybe.

**Solution**:
Just use [v3](https://docs.rs/clap/3.2.23/clap/index.html) until another solution comes up. (Either a better crate or better options for clap.)  v4 has a number of stylistic regressions, including [less friendly error messages](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/10axc9u/clap_v41_a_rust_cli_argument_parser/).

An *alternate solution*, that I present only half-seriously:
Rust has excellent foreign-function interface.  You could front-end your rust with another language and use a more ergonomic and modern CLI framework like Python's [Typer](https://typer.tiangolo.com/) with interface via [PyO3](https://maxwellrules.com/programming/rusty-python.html).

Comment: Regarding error message quality, this has since improved in [this issue](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/issues/4638), particularly due to [this PR](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/pull/4798).